# Passing cookie from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: java, php, cookies

I can pass cookie from HTTP to HTTPS but not HTTPS to HTTP.

I can see all the cookie value in HTTPS site.

But I can only see cookie value in HTTP created by itself.

So how can I pass cookie from HTTPS to HTTP?

Comment: If the cookie has its `secure` parameter set, it won't be sent without SSL. If you need it to go over insecure connections, remove the `secure` option, but know that you are potentially degrading your security _severely_ and don't put _anything_ of value in that cookie.

Comment: Is it the session cookie you want to share? A session cookie especially should not be shared between HTTP and HTTPS, because it leaves you open to session-hijacking. There is a method though, that separates authentication from maintaining the session, so you could share the session cookie. Let me know if that is your scenario.

Comment: @Thihara - I wrote it all down in this small article: [Secure session cookie with SSL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_nomim_cookie).